# Running a batch with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I need to save a bunch (several thousand) of images with imagemagick.

I'm totally new to it, and its documentation seems totally opaque and totally labyrinth. Where's the quickstart guide?

Looking at it, I think I want to use `mogrify`.

so I cd to my program files directory where I installed imagemagick.

I run `mogrify -format png *.png` as I see in various examples.

It says:

```
mogrify: unable to open image `fgimg\': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenB
lob/2489.
mogrify: unable to open file `fgimg\' @ png.c/ReadPNGImage/2865.
```

How do I instruct it to run on all images in the subdirectory \fgimg?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not clear how you need to process the images. Your example command takes all png images and overwrites them with images in the same format: png.

Comment: Yes, that's all I need to do.

Saving them again with imagemagick fixes problems inherent in those files. I described the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007496/a-batch-gimp-png-script

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that you're hitting the limit of how much you can put on a command line. You need to split it into chunks that will fit. This should work better:

```
find -name '*.png' -print0 | xargs -0 -r mogrify -format png
```

The `-print0` and `-0` are used to handle spaces in filenames, and the `-r` means don't run mogrify if there's nothing to do.